# How do I make an entire Table a button/link to another HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this table, that should be a button that link to another page. The reason is that the values of the table should be changeable with data from a database. The parameter can be changes to pH for example and the Value to 7 or something. But the table/button shall link to the same page. Where it is possible to set the Target.

So far this i what i got:

```
<table class="Button" >
    <tr>
        <td class="parameter"> Temperature</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="Value">23&#x2103</td>    
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="Target">Target: 30&#x2103 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So how do i make it a link/button?

Comment: Use onclick, and redirect the client with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onclick` and redirect your page.

Or wrap your table with `<a>`

```html
<table class="Button" onclick="location.href='yourpage.html'" >
    <tr>
        <td class="parameter"> Temperature</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="Value">23&#x2103</td>    
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="Target">Target: 30&#x2103 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why involve JavaScript when plain HTML has a built in solution? (Which won't break the ability of people to select the link with linear (e.g. keyboard based) navigation).

Answer (score 1):

The same way as anything else.

You put an `<a>` element (with an `href` attribute) around it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into a link element:

```
<a href="LINK.html">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="parameter"> Temperature</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Value">23&#x2103</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Target">Target: 30&#x2103 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

And if you wanna have a button, add a button element to that:

```
<button style="color:black; background-color:white; border-radius:5px;">
    <a href="LINK.html">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="parameter"> Temperature</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Value">23&#x2103</td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Target">Target: 30&#x2103 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript onClick event or put `<a>` tag around it

Html

```
 <table class="button" onClick="linkTo('https://www.google.com')">
    .
    .
    .
 </table>
```

Java Script

```
<script>
       function linkTo(var link){
         window.location = link;
       }

</script>
```

Css for mouse point

```
<style>
 table.button{
     cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```